Notepad++ How can I copy multiple lines in a pattern and insert a new copy with some edited content
I want to duplicate multiple lines of code
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="doctitle" -->
<title>Page Title</title>
<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->

I want to change the tag name and either add or remove the html markup around the target phrase
    <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="doctitle" -->
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
    <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="pagetitle" -->
    Page Title
    <!-- InstanceEndEditable -->



Ctrl+H
Find what: (<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="doctitle" -->\R)<title>(.+?)</title>(\R<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->\R)
Replace with: $0$1$2$3
TICK Match case
TICK Wrap around
Search Mode Regular expression
UNTICK . matches newline
Replace all

Explanation:
(                   # group 1
    <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="doctitle" -->      # literally
    \R                  # any kind of line break
)                   # end group 1
<title>             # literally
(.+?)               # group 2, 1 or more any character, not greeddy
</title>            # literally
(                   # group 3
    \R                  # any kind of line break
    <!-- InstanceEndEditable -->                        # literally
    \R                  # any kind of line break
)                   # end group 3

Replacement:
$0          # the whole match
$1          # content of group 1
$2          # content of group 2
$3          # content of group 3

Screenshot (before):

Screenshot (after):


Thank You very much

@MichaelB: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, How to accept an answer
